# How to map query fields to database table column?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

For example:

`typeDefs`:

```sh
type User {
  userId: ID!
  userNme: String
  userEmail: String
}
```

In database, `users` table has three columns: `user_id`, `user_nme`, `user_email`.

Now, the client sends a `GraphQL` query named `userById` with two fields: `user_id` and `user_nme`.

The `SQL` statements of my `DAO` layer is:

```js
async function findUserById(id: string) {
  const sql = `
    SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ?;
  `
  return db('users').raw(sql, [id]);
}
```

As you can see, the `SQL` statement selects all columns of the `users` table from the database.

How to map the specific `fields` of client sends to the `SQL` `select` statement?

Expected result:

```js
async function findUserById(id: string) {
  const sql = `
    SELECT 
      user_id, 
      user_nme
    FROM users WHERE user_id = ?;
  `
  return db('users').raw(sql, [id]);
}
```

Simply say is: I just want to query the fields that the client wants to query.

Comment: You can check which fields are sent under an if statement and change your query accordingly. Which is more secure

Comment: Converting GraphQL queries to SQL efficiently is ***hard***, particularly once you start dealing with filtering, relationships and pagination. I would highly advise looking at existing tools like [join-monster](https://github.com/acarl005/join-monster), [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io), [PostGraphile](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile) or [Hasura](https://hasura.io) rather than trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @DanielRearden Thanks. I know Prisma can do this, but I am using apollographql stack